# Set ImageButton image Programmatically

Tags: java, android

when I click the ImageButtonit prompted me to chose an image from the device, and then my intention is to set it as the image of that button.Also the code only works when the image is retrieved from 'Photos' so if i could get some tips on how to make it work on all of the options that would be great.

here is my code:

```
package lucas.app_2001;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class Shout extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton b1;
    private static final int SELECT_PICTURE = 1;
    String selectedImagePath;
    RelativeLayout myLayout1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_shout);
        b1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        myLayout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myLayout1);
        findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
               b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        // in onCreate or any event where your want the user to
                        // select a file
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setType("image/*");
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,
                                "Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
                    }
                });
    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);

                b1.setImageResource(selectedImageUri);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * helper to retrieve the path of an image URI
     */
    public String getPath(Uri contentUri) {
            String res = null;
            String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){;
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                res = cursor.getString(column_index);
            }
            cursor.close();
            return res;
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it helps:

```
   public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                selectedImagePath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
                Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath);
                b1.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I had to add     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> to the manifest file to make it work but this is the solution that best worked.

Answer (score 1):

> set it as the image of that button

Easy! use [public void setImageBitmap (Bitmap bm)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap))

> the code only works when the image is retrieved from 'Photos'

Right your code will fail because, pictures stored in apps such as google photos/drive have a different type of path that cursor cannot resolve.

change your `getPath()` method to

```
/**
 * Get a file path from a Uri. This will get the the path for Storage Access
 * Framework Documents, as well as the _data field for the MediaStore and
 * other file-based ContentProviders.
 *
 * @param context The context.
 * @param uri     The Uri to query.
 */
@TargetApi(19)
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    final boolean isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;

    // DocumentProvider
    if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {
        // ExternalStorageProvider
        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            if ("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)) {
                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];
            }

            // TODO handle non-primary volumes
        }
        // DownloadsProvider
        else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);
        }
        // MediaProvider
        else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }
    }
    // MediaStore (and general)
    else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);
    }
    // File
    else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_PICTURE) {
            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), selectedImageUri);
                b1.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```